# HTTP Delete send with Angular HTTP Client is fired - not received by server

Tags: angular, spring, http

I am working on an App including CRUD-functionality. I use Spring for the backend implementation, Angular for the frontend. In the frontend, I use Angular's http client like this to delete an entity (The following code is shortened for the sake of brevity):

Component:

```
export class RecipeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private recipeService : RecipeService) { }

    deleteElement (id : number) {
        this.recipeService.deleteRecipe(id).subscribe();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
export class RecipeService {

    deleteRecipe (id : number) : Observable<{}> {
      return this.http.delete('http://localhost:8080/recipe/' + id);
    }

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }
}
```

When executing the function, I can find the http-delete request in the network tab:
[image]

The Spring Controller looks (shortend) like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(path="/recipe")
public class RESTController {
    @Autowired
    private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;


@DeleteMapping(path="/{id}")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity deleteRecipe (@RequestBody Recipe deletedRecipe, @PathVariable("id") int id) {

    try {
        [...]
        }
    } catch (RecipeNotFoundException e) {
        [...]       
    }
}


}
```

Yet, my backend does not receive the request. The strange thing is, Posts or Gets work fine.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks and best!

Comment: Does it work if you send the request via curl? `curl -vSX DELETE http://localhost:8080/recipe/id?`

Comment: it returns `400` which means bad request. Are you sure of your implementation in Spring? Could you share it?

Comment: So, the curl log is:

`*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> DELETE /recipe/301 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 20:53:36 GMT
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0`

Which does not help me a lot - the entity is still there. When I send the request in Postman, the entity is deleted.

Comment: @GuerricP, I put the important bits in the question up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `400 Bad request` is very likely a "body is missing" error. Remove `@RequestBody Recipe deletedRecipe` from the method parameters since you don't provide the entity to delete, the `id` is enough.

Comment: That's been it! I wrote the controller long before I needed it and forgot about this.